# How to do validation in $ionicPopup?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to use `$ionicPopup` to handle login/registration on my app.
I'm opening it from a service, so I created a new scope and attached it to the ionicPopup.

It looks something like this:

```
$ionicPopup.show
  template: '''
    <form name="loginForm" novalidate>
      ...
    </form>
  ''',
  scope: $scope,
  buttons: [
    { 
      text: 'Cancel',
    },
    {
      text: '<b>Save</b>',
      type: 'button-positive',
      onTap: ( e ) ->

        form = $scope.loginForm #why is it undefined?
    } 
  ]
```

So I named the form as `loginForm`, and I want to access it inside the `onTap` function to handle validation. But the `loginForm` does not exists on the `$scope`, like it would in a normal form validation inside a controller.

How should I handle the validation here?

Comment: You can use html5 validation in your form

Comment: Unfortunately that's not enough for me. I would like to take advantage of the ngFormController and ngModelController to handle validation, but the provided $scope does not have these values.

Comment: Awesome even I am at stuck at the same problem and the reason you get it undefined is because Ionic creates a new scope on the popup as seen https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/js/angular/service/popup.js#L17 line 280. I am still wondering why this is done. Any clues anyone.

Comment: @Zaje: have you figure it out a solution ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you give `ionicpopup` a `templateUrl`, instead of hard coded template string, you can use a regular controller inside the template that does the validation.

I deleted all the `ionicpopup` related buttons and placed the necessary buttons inside the template.

In this way I was able to control the `ionicpopup`'s state from the controller (i.e. closing the popup).

Comment: can you please share the jsFiddle example which you have mentioned?

Comment: the only issue is if your popup scrolls due to the keyboard sliding in the buttons aren't visible

Comment: @gsanta: Can you share that jsFiddle example? (I'm interested). And what if my popup template is used in multiple controllers ?

Comment: 2 years people still waiting your jsfiddle :)

Answer (score 0):

I found solution, it works for me. All you need to change is define in controller your form:

```
$scope.form = {
    loginForm: {}
};
    $ionicPopup.show
      template: '''
        <form name="form.loginForm" novalidate>
          ...
        </form>
      ''',
      scope: $scope,
      buttons: [
        { 
          text: 'Cancel',
        },
        {
          text: '<b>Save</b>',
          type: 'button-positive',
          onTap: ( e ) ->

            form = $scope.form.loginForm
        } 
      ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using my solution, you don't have to delete the ionic popup buttons.
What you can do to validate, is by using ng-Model.

You don't have to use `<form>`. So I remove `<form>`.

```
  $ionicPopup.show
  template: '<input name="username" ng-model="data.username">',
  scope: $scope,
  buttons: [
    { 
      text: 'Cancel',
    },
    {
      text: '<b>Save</b>',
      type: 'button-positive',
      onTap: ( e )
        var user_name = $scope.data.username
        // do validation here
        if(user_name != 'undefined') {
           ...
        }
    } 
  ]
```

I prefer not to remove the ionic popup buttons. Hope it is useful to others.
 cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
onTap: ( e )
    e.eventPreventDefault()
    var user_name = $scope.data.username
    // do validation here
    if(user_name != 'undefined') {
       ...
}
```

Comment: Hi @Luiz, thank you for your answer. Try to explain why your code should be the accepted answer to the question.